# double y-axis figure with bars and line graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart, line

I was trying to fix the following graph
[image]

My code so far is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{book.data
}
in  Unemployement   
1   7.8
2   9
3   8.9 
`95 9.1
`96 9.7 
`97 9.6 
`98 10.8
`99 11.7
`00 11.1
`01 10.2
`02 10.3
`03 9.7
`04 10.5
`05 9.8
`06 8.9
`07 8.3
`08 7.7
`09 9.5
`10 12.5
`11 17.7
`12 24.2
`13 27.2
`14 26.3
`15 24.9
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb] 
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
        \begin{axis}[
            ybar,
            xlabel = Year,
            xmin = 0.5,
            xmax = 24.5,
            ymin = 0,
            ymax = 35000,
            axis x line* = bottom,
            axis y line* = left,
            ylabel= \$,
            width= 1.1*\textwidth,
            height = \textwidth,
            ymajorgrids = true,
enlarge x limits=0.01,
            bar width = 3mm,
            xticklabels = \empty,
            extra x ticks = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24},
            extra x tick labels = {\tiny'92, \tiny'93, \tiny'94, \tiny'95, \tiny'96, \tiny'97, \tiny'98, \tiny'99, \tiny'00, \tiny'01, \tiny'02, \tiny'03, \tiny'04, \tiny'05, \tiny'06, \tiny'07, \tiny'08, \tiny'09, \tiny'10, \tiny'11, \tiny'12, \tiny'13, \tiny'14, \tiny'15},
legend columns=2,
        legend cell align=left,
        legend style={
                at={(0.5,-0.2)},
                anchor=north,
                column sep=1ex}
            ]
            \addplot+[mark=none,very thick] coordinates {
                (1,11176.45844)
(2, 10401.98299)    
(3,11091.28386) 
(4,12959.32432) 
(5,13749.11515) 
(6,13427.83249) 
(7,13472.13764) 
(8,13245.18946) 
(9,12042.95373) 
(10,12538.17883)    
(11,14110.31339)    
(12,18477.57841)    
(13,21955.10409)    
(14,22551.73574)    
(15,24801.15781)    
(16,28827.32636)    
(17,31997.28201)    
(18,29710.9703) 
(19,26919.36164)    
(20,25914.68155)    
(21,22242.68193)    
(22,21842.70331)    
(23,21627.35429)    
(24,18035.55432)
            };
\legend{GDP per capita (current US\$)};
        \end{axis} 

 \begin{axis}[
    %scale only axis,
    axis y line*=right,
    axis x line=none,%axis on top,
    %xtick=\empty,
 width= 1.1*\textwidth,
            height = \textwidth,
            ymajorgrids = true,
enlarge x limits=0.01,
       %major x tick style = transparent,
    %ybar=5*\pgflinewidth,
       axis line style={-},
    %bar width=14pt,
    ylabel = {\%},
xmajorgrids,
     scaled y ticks = false,
    ymin=0, ymax=30,
    %legend columns=2,
%    legend cell align=left,
%    legend style={
%        at={(0.5,-0.2)},
%        anchor=north,
%        column sep=1ex
%    }
    ]
     \addplot table[x=in,y=Unemployment] {book.data};\addlegendentry{Unemployment Rate, total (\% of total labour force) }
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some problems with your code. First of all, the backticks in your datafile should be removed, and I assume that the first three x-coordinates should be `92`, `93` and `94`?

A second problem is that the x-coordinates are different. In the data from the file you had used the first column, while for the barplot you had used 1,2,... To fix that problem you can use `x expr=\coordindex+1` instead of `x=in` in the `\addplot table ...`.

I also demonstrated one way of having a single legend, and simplified the definition of the xticklabels.

Two get two of the bars in a different color, I think you need a third `axis` environment, where you only plot those two. I see I picked 2012 instead of 2014, but that's easily fixed by yourself.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{book.data}
in  Unemployement   
92   7.8
93   9
94   8.9 
95 9.1
96 9.7 
97 9.6 
98 10.8
99 11.7
00 11.1
01 10.2
02 10.3
03 9.7
04 10.5
05 9.8
06 8.9
07 8.3
08 7.7
09 9.5
10 12.5
11 17.7
12 24.2
13 27.2
14 26.3
15 24.9
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfplotsset{lineplot/.style={blue,mark=*,sharp plot,line legend}}
        \begin{axis}[
            ybar,
            xlabel = Year,
            xmin = 0.5,
            xmax = 24.5,
            ymin = 0,
            ymax = 35000,
            axis x line* = bottom,
            axis y line* = left,
            ylabel= \$,
            width= \textwidth,
            height = 0.8\textwidth,
            ymajorgrids = true,
            enlarge x limits=0.01,
            bar width = 3mm,
            xtick= {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24},
            xticklabels= {'92, '93, '94, '95, '96, '97, '98, '99, '00, '01, '02, '03, '04, '05, '06, '07, '08, '09, '10, '11, '12, '13, '14, '15},
            x tick label style={font=\tiny},
            legend columns=2,
            legend cell align=left,
            legend style={
                at={(0.5,-0.2)},
                anchor=north,
                column sep=1ex}
            ]
            \addplot+[mark=none,very thick,label=barplot] coordinates {
                (1,11176.45844)
                (2, 10401.98299)    
                (3,11091.28386) 
                (4,12959.32432) 
                (5,13749.11515) 
                (6,13427.83249) 
                (7,13472.13764) 
                (8,13245.18946) 
                (9,12042.95373) 
                (10,12538.17883)    
                (11,14110.31339)    
                (12,18477.57841)    
                (13,21955.10409)    
                (14,22551.73574)    
                (15,24801.15781)    
                (16,28827.32636)    
                (18,29710.9703) 
                (19,26919.36164)    
                (20,25914.68155)    
                (22,21842.70331)    
                (23,21627.35429)    
                (24,18035.55432)
            };
                \addlegendentry{GDP per capita (current US\$)};


                \addlegendimage{lineplot}
                \addlegendentry{Unemployment Rate, total (\% of total labour force)}
        \end{axis} 
        \begin{axis}[
            ybar,
            xlabel = Year,
            xmin = 0.5,
            xmax = 24.5,
            ymin = 0,
            ymax = 35000,
            hide axis,
            width= \textwidth,
            height = 0.8\textwidth,
            ymajorgrids = true,
            enlarge x limits=0.01,
            bar width = 3mm,
            xtick=\empty,
            ]
            \addplot+[mark=none,very thick,label=barplot,fill=orange!70,draw=orange] coordinates {
                (17,31997.28201)    
                (21,22242.68193)    
            };
        \end{axis} 
 \begin{axis}[
            xmin = 0.5,
            xmax = 24.5,
            axis y line=right,
            axis x line=none,
            width= \textwidth,
            height = 0.8\textwidth,
            ymajorgrids = true,
            enlarge x limits=0.01,
            axis line style={-},
            ylabel = {\%},
            xmajorgrids,
            scaled y ticks = false,
            ymin=0, ymax=35,
    ]
     \addplot [lineplot] table[x expr=\coordindex+1,y=Unemployement] {book.data};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What about the different colour of the two column bars?

Comment: @giannis Forgot to think about that. See edited answer.